# How to configure internal LDAP realm within the WebLogic for BPM app

Tags: weblogic, business-process-management

I am new to Oracle BPM 11g. I am trying to deploy one hellow world application (using :- http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/fmw/obpm/11g/r1/firstProcess/firstprocess_obpm11g.htm) in my local WL server.

In the Deploying and Testing the Application part , i need to connect to the internal LDAP realm within the WebLogic server , in order to map the Reviewer and Requester roles to a user in the LDAP. To do that i follow all the steps (Mapping the Studio Role to an LDAP Role ) till step 3 and I have succesfully conected my local WL server, but in Step 4 Realm is not getting automatically populated.

Can anybody please help me to configure local LDAP realm with in my WL as i can accomplish the 4th step of Mapping the Studio Role to an LDAP Role section in that document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

now i know whats the problem.

in the tutorial, it didnt state that must configure a client and server node.

meaning that in order to complete the tutorial, must set up a server first and deploy it there.

to create a connection, must put the server's IP address as the Weblogic Hostname.

and the jazn.com will populate automatically.